# How to automatically execute a shell command after saving a file in Vim?

Tags: vim, autocmd

This is because I'd like to automatically run tests after each file save.

I have looked at `autocmd` and `BufWritePost` but cannot make it work.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This runs `run_tests.sh` after any file is saved, with the current filename as the only  parameter:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost * !run_tests.sh <afile>
```

View the auto-command with:

```
:autocmd BufWritePost *
```

And remove all auto-commands from the previous with:

```
:autocmd! BufWritePost *
```

Comment: Is there a way to to something like this ?: if a file named tests.html is present in the current directory OR in the directory just above then run command testprog tests.html OR cd .. testprog tests.html ?

Comment: @Running Turle: I would create a function for this and then use it in an autocmd. Use `filereadable()` to test if there is a file and then act accordingly.

Comment: This works, but what if you want to pass the full path to the file. Is it possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272435/vim-autocommand-on-write-pass-full-file-path

Comment: How to do this quietly in the background so you won't get the output?

Comment: @botenvouwer Try `:autocmd BufWritePost * silent !run_tests.sh <afile>`. Output will still be written to the console, but vim won't wait for you to acknowledge. Send a "quiet"/"silent" option to your specific command or add `>/dev/null` to blackhole its output if need be.

Comment: and for before save it's `BufWritePre`

Answer (score 1):

put this into your `.vimrc` file:

(take `raml2html doc/api.raml > public/api_doc.html` as a command example)

```
autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.raml silent! !raml2html doc/api.raml > public/api_doc.html
```

notice:

- `silent!` will hide all the output of this command
- `:silent` if you are using vim7.3-, and `silent!` if using vim7.3+
- need to quit and restart vim, to make `.vimrc` take effect.