# Why does sudo change a blocking command to a non-blocking command when used in a while-loop?

Tags: bash, while-loop, rsync, sudo, inotify

Or: **How do I prevent a sudo'ed rsync from infinite firing in a while-loop?**
Because that's both what (feels like) is happening and I don't get it.

I am trying to set up a watch for syncing modified files, and it works fine. However, once I introduce the required `sudo` to the `rsync` command, a single `inotify` event causes the `rsync` command to fire indefinitely.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e modify -e move -e create -e delete /var/test | while read line; do
    sudo rsync -ah --del --progress --stats --update "$line" "/home/test/" 
done
```

When you edit a file, `rsync` goes in rapid fire mode. But lose the `sudo` (and use folders to which you have permissions, of course) and the script works as expected.

1. Why is this?
2. How do I make this work correctly with the `sudo` command?

Comment: When you apply sudo, I suspect rsync is waiting for password to be entered. and that's how you think rsync is running indefinitely. Have you tried, running sudo'ed rsync on command prompt as a standalone command ? does it ask for password ? if yes, you might want to use expect command to automate the password entry.

Comment: The command works fine without a password - I have `rsync` allowed in `sudoers` with `nopassword`. The command also executes properly, it syncs the file. But it keeps doing it over and over until I break the script.

Comment: Ahh !! got your problem !! the thing is when you edit any file, most of the editor create swap file or even update the timestamp. this issues many modify notifications to "inotifywait" you should be passing "-e close_write" switch to inotifywait command. in fact, just don't look for modifications. see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300835/too-many-inotify-events-while-editing-in-vim

Comment: Unfortunately, this is unrelated. Otherwise this behavior would also affect the non-sudo variant. Besides, I also want to monitor creations, deletions and moves. I am testing using `echo test > test.txt`, no temp files or attribute changes here.

Comment: thats correct, echo would not do that. try "vim /var/test/a.txt" and keep editing it while your script is running. Whenever you press enter in vim, you will see rsync running. no ?

Comment: I don't see a condition in your while loop that says, "ok, enough, lets quit".  Isn't `inotifywait` meant to keep running forever? Good luck.

Comment: **@shellter:** It's supposed to run indefinitely, and the original script works fine. The introduction of `sudo` breaks this behavior, and that is the scope of this question. **@Icarus3:** Probably. I believe you. :) I haven't checked, this is irrelevant. **@All:** I answered my own question, but I don't understand why `sudo` breaks the expected bash behavior.

Comment: your heading says "how do I prevent a sudo'ed rsync from infinite firing in a while-loop?", but NOT "why is  my infinite loop not working any more, after I have added sudo", which is what your comment indicates is the problem. Glad you found a solution to your problem and that you posted the answer here. Don't forget to accept your answer with a chk-mark to increase your reputation points!. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer, found it by experimenting. But I have no idea why this is. Please someone tell me why `sudo` in this loop breaks the expected blocking behavior.

Since `sudo` breaks the script, we can distance ourselves from `sudo` by using a wrapper:
**This is correct:**

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e modify /var/test | while read line; do
    sh -c 'sudo rsync -ah "$line" "/home/test/"'
done
```

Weird thing is: Pull the `sudo` out of the wrapper and we have the old faulty behavior again. Very strange.
**This is wrong:**

```
inotifywait -m -r --format '%w%f' -e modify /var/test | while read line; do
    sudo sh -c 'rsync -ah "$line" "/home/test/"'
done
```