# How to make vim run "cpplint" after every "save" command?

Tags: vim, save, autocmd, cpplint

I wish that each time I ":w" to save a .h/.cpp file in vim, vim will automatically run cpplint to check my format, and change the file if needed.

How to specify this with autocmd?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vim: how to execute automatically execute a shell command after saving a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627701/vim-how-to-execute-automatically-execute-a-shell-command-after-saving-a-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use an autocmd for this, you can simply add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufWrite *.cpp :! cppcheck %
```

However, I would personally recommend using a syntax checking plugin for this. The very popular [vim-syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) supports cpplint out of the box. You can use the following line to set `cpplint` as the syntax checker for C++ files.

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = ['cpplint']
```

The advantage of using a plugin is that it will integrate with Vim and highlight where there are issues, rather than just dumping textual output to stdout.

PS: make sure `cpplint` is in your `$PATH`, without it neither approach will work.