# Vim autocommand on write - pass full file path

Tags: bash, vim

I want to execute a bash script whenever I save a file in Vim. The problem is I don't how can I, or if it's possible to pass the full path to the file, rather than just the file name, or relative path that was opened.

This is the code I'm using, it works, however only relative paths, which is useless to me.

```
autocmd BufWritePost * !~/.config/nvim/scripts/on_save.sh <afile>
```

Is there any way to pass the full file path to the bash script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found it:

```
autocmd BufWritePost * !~/.config/nvim/scripts/on_save.sh %:p
```

The **%:p** does it

Comment: You forgot to mention *where* you found it: `:help filename-modifiers`.

Comment: Actually I found it on ServerFault or some other QA but thanks for reference

Comment: web link for the lazy folks like me: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers